# Enable /register page to logged in users in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to enable /register page to logged in users and restrict for non logged in users in laravel 5.2. I tried changing \app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php page constructer to view /register page to logged in users but it didn't work...

```
public function __construct() {
     $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => ['logout', 'getRegister', 'postRegister']]);
}
```

It would be great help if someone can look into this.

Comment: Laravel provides a quick way to scaffold all of the routes and views you need for authentication using one simple command: `php artisan make:auth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add inside auth group middleware all your routes that redirect to views visible to the logged in users.

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
       Route::get('/register','your_controller@your_method');
    });
```

Comment: Hi I need to use existing /register functionality. So I don't understand how to use 'your_controller@your_method'. I'm really sorry if I'm wrong and thanks so much for the help. I'm upvoting you as a thanks :)