# How to use the password reset form for logged in user in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to use the `auth\passwords\reset` blade from the `auth()` scaffold package to let a user change their password once they are logged in. At the moment, this page does not show up as it's not added to the proper middleware route as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38701883/enable-register-page-to-logged-in-users-in-laravel-5-2)

I'm trying to develop a simple form with a `password` and `confirm password` field, which the user could use to change their password to set a new password.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated...